# Check to see if data is the same before writing over it

Tags: python, bash, arduino

I have the temperature coming from my arduino through the serial port on my mac. I need to write the data to a file, i don't want my script to write the data from /dev/tty.usbserial-A5025XZE (serial port) if the data is the same or if it is nothing. The temperature is the the format "12.32" and is sent every 5s.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't read the file before writing out to it?

Comment: the script needs to be a loop that runs every 5 seconds, it needs to read the file first compare, it to the new data and overwrite the data if its different

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to read the file before writing to it:

```
def is_file_identical(data):
    f_data = ''
    with open("path/to/filename") as f:
        f_data = f.read()

    return data == f_data

print is_file_identical('foo') # True
print is_file_identical('bar') # False
```

Answer (score 0):

The script which reads data from serial port and writes data to the file can handle the case when data is identical. You could do something like:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial(0)
t = ""
while True:
    newT = serial.readline()
    if t!=newT:
        with open("/your/file") as f:
            f.write(newT)
        t=newT
```

Which will append a new temperature to /your/file each time the temperature changes. Of course you need to adapt `serial.Serial(0)` and `/your/file`. I assumed you use something like [this](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/shortintro.html).

Comment: What would i adapt "serial.Serial(0)" too?

Comment: According to the [PySerial documentation](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/shortintro.html), `serial.Serial(0)` will open the first serial port, typically you will want to open a named port `serial.Serial('/dev/ttyS0', 19200, timeout=1)` as like as in the example.

Answer (score 0):

Just save the output from the arduino to a temporary variable and compare it to another that is the last value written to a file. If it is different, change the last value written to the new temperature and write it to the file.